# All Payment Modules in Prestasop Not Displaying

Tags: module, prestashop, payment, prestashop-1.6

please help me

None of my payment modules are being displayed on the final checkout page . I have installed and configured the following modules correctly

1. payment by cheque
2. Bank Wire
3. Cash on delivery.
4. Payu (payment gateway like paypal )

All the above worked fine until past month when they stopped displaying on the front end website. The appear as installed in the back end .
all the above payment options have been given permission of all countries , users and products.

all the carriers are however being displayed with their images.

I am a newbie and harassed by this . Please help me what I should do.

Comment: i got a similar problem, it is solved when i disabled the stock managment, if not, try to see if there's currency or client group restrictions

Comment: I dont have stock management but it was resolved after the payment.tpl was hooked in on the page correctly in global.css

Comment: I'm sorry, @ArpanJain, can you explain a little bit more about what you did? What do you mean with hooking payment.tpl correctly in global.css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `config/defines.inc.php`, 
change

```
define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false);
```

to

```
define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);
```

And reload your final checkout page to see if there are mistakes somewhere.